# Css text-overflow ellipsis in a select

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, frontend, zurb-foundation-5

I just want to add an ellipsis to the end of the option selected in a select when the text is truncated. (It should work in any modern browser, specially chrome)

How can I do it? (I prefer to no use a whole library just for this)

I´m using

- angular 1.3
- foundation 5

foundation helps, but only works in safari using this lines:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

I believe I´ll have to do it manually, in that case, Which is the best way?

Thx in advanced

Comment: maybe `-webkit-text-overflow` and other vendor prefixes, or `-webkit-ellipsis` and its vendor prefixes.

Comment: Thx @yak613 I tried that, but the only prefix it accepts is -o- for opera

Comment: the others come with the property?